# create button that will make script run on click

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I have code which runs directly when the page opens. Instead I want it to work when I click a button. After I click the button my code will perform an action and the button should get removed.

It's jQuery but I need it to run only on my click

```
function get_just_hazardous_words_from_config() {
    let hazardous_words_from_config = get_hazardous_words_config();
    let hazardous_words = [];

    $.each(hazardous_words_from_config, function(k, v) {
        hazardous_words.push(v.Keyword);
    });

    return hazardous_words;
}
```

Comment: So what specific problem are you having accomplishing your goal and wht is your question? Tke a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click or https://api.jquery.com/on. Although note that the `return` becomes completely redundant for a click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button and try this:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
       get_just_hazardous_words_from_config();
      });
    });

 function get_just_hazardous_words_from_config() {
        let hazardous_words_from_config = get_hazardous_words_config();
        let hazardous_words = [];

    $.each(hazardous_words_from_config, function(k, v) {
        hazardous_words.push(v.Keyword);
    });

    return hazardous_words;
}
</script>
```